# Cannot make Yii nested menu "active", with parameters

Tags: php, css, yii

So I have a nested dropdown menu, using CMenu Widgets.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
   'activeCssClass' => 'active',
   'activateParents' => true,
   'items' => '
         ... (several menus)
      array('label' => 'Profil',
            'url' => array('/profile/profile'),
            'active' => Yii::app()->controller->id == 'profile' || Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'profile' || Yii::app()->controller->action->id->params == 'id',
            'items' => array(
                  array('label' => 'Profil Saya', 'url' => array('/profile/profile&id='.Yii::app()->user->name),),
                  array('label' => 'Ubah Password', 'url' => array('/profile/password'),),
             ),
         ),
);
```

What doesn't work is when I click "Profil Saya", the active css only works on the menu "Profil", not "Profil Saya" too.
The URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost/monev/index.php?r=profile/profile&id=safira
```

But my code above doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in your route added `&id='.Yii::app()->user->name`. So you can add active class using `itemOptions`. Here a small example. Hope this help you:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
    'activeCssClass' => 'active',
    'activateParents' => true,
    'items' =>
      //...
      array(
         'label' => 'Profil',
         'url' => array('/profile/profile'),
         'active' => Yii::app()->controller->id == 'profile' || Yii::app()->controller->action->id == 'profile' || Yii::app()->controller->action->id->params == 'id',
         'items' => array(
             array(
                 'label' => 'Profil Saya',
                 'url' => array('/profile/profile&id='.Yii::app()->user->name),
                 'itemOptions' => array(
                     'class' => ((strpos($this->getRoute(), 'profile/profile') !== false) ? 'active' : null)
                 )
             ),
             array('label' => 'Ubah Password', 'url' => array('/profile/password'),),
         ),
      ),
    )
);
```